# What should be done with the [helper] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I recently came across this tag. It seems to have many questions asked about it, from [Problem with importing helper. Any advice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70412472/problem-with-importing-helper-any-advice) to [Configuration 'Run Script: android' is missing in 'launch.json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70269998/configuration-run-script-android-is-missing-in-launch-json) to [I need help trouble shooting a syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69716220/i-need-help-trouble-shooting-a-syntax-error) to [Discord bot is not running for some reason CLOSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095576/discord-bot-is-not-running-for-some-reason-closed). I don't know much about the tag, but it seems like these are all irrelevant, and should have the tag removed from them.

According to the tag wiki:

> A helper is a method commonly used in object-oriented programming to provide additional functionality to classes that not directly associated with the class.  This is known as an Inversion of Responsibility.
>
> Helper methods are typically grouped into a single helper class through the delegation pattern.

"associated with **the class**"- what is "the class"? The information on the tag wiki also needs improvement. Because there are still a few questions where the tag is used properly, I don't think it should be burninated, but the tag wiki and off-topic questions (which mostly seem to ask for help) should be improved. Again, I have no experience with helpers, but as an example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68551421/laravel-str-helper-class-doesnt-work-with-unicode) seems to be on-topic. What should be done with this tag?